# Shell: Unable to get the return value from ssh connection

Tags: shell, email, unix, sh

I have a script test_server_conn.sh and two servers i.e Serv1 and Serv2. Trying to execute the script from Serv1 and establish a ssh connection with Serv2. Checking for a file presence and thereafter returning a value.

`test_server_conn.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


test_file(){
     echo "Establishing ssh connection with Serv2."
     sshpass -p pswd ssh uid@serv2

     retval=""
     FILE=/etc/docker
     if [ -d "$FILE" ]; 
     then
       echo "$FILE is a directory."
       retval=0
     else
       echo "Check and try again. Closing the connection from Serv2."
       retval=1
     fi
     return "${retval}"
}

echo "Execution started from Serv1..."
test_file
retval=$?

if [ "${retval}" -eq 0 ];
then
  echo "Directory is ready"
else
  echo "Directory is not ready."
fi
```

The script executes but fails to stop the execution.

`Actual results`:

```
Execution started from Serv1...
Establishing ssh connection with Serv2.
<nothing after this and the curser keeps blinking>
```

`Expected results`:

```
Execution started from Serv1...
Establishing ssh connection with Serv2.
Directory is ready/ Directory is not ready.
```

Not getting why this doesn't returns anything and goes in a hang state? How can I return the value from ssh connection without getting any issues as such?

Comment: You are executing `sh`, not `ssh`.

Comment: @Eupheus

Where are you specifying Serv2 (while attempting to ssh (sh is a typo I assume)?

Also, the SSH syntax is wrong. It's 
```ssh userid@server

 (and not ssh user@passwd)
```
Recommended approach is to configure passwordless SSH between server1 and server2.

Check this thread:

```https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password```

Comment: @KamilCuk,@Sharad Thanks. Corrected the typo in the question.

Comment: Instead of `test_file; retval=$?; if [ "${retval}" -eq 0 ]; then ...` just write `if test_file; then ...`

Comment: `Check and try again.` sound suspiciously like an error message.  Error messages belong on stderr. `echo "Check and ..." >&2`